# Export Notes from Entourage to Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app, ms-office

Is it Possible to export the notes made in Entourage 2008 V 12.0.0 to Apple Mail notes? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can Export your notes in Entourage by going to **File** > **Export...** or selecting **Shift** + **Command** + **S**, and then check boxing only **Notes**. When this is exported to a location of your choice (e.g. Desktop), it saves as a **.rge**. This file type cannot be opened in Apple Mail. **Show Package Contents** reveals a **Notes** folder with your exported notes encrypted inside that can only be opened via Entourage. I more or less ran into a dead end trying to figure this out for you.  As far as I could figure out, this cannot be done any easier way than the following:

- Open Entourage
- Go to **Notes**
- Go to **Edit** > **Select All** (or **Command** + **A**) to select all of your notes
- Go to **File** > **Print** (or **Command** + **P**) to act like you will print all of your notes
- Select **PDF** > **Save As PDF...** and select a location of your choice (e.g. Desktop)
- Try and import these into **Apple Mail**, and if unsuccessful import the PDFs you just created into [**Evernote**](http://www.evernote.com)
- Rejoice or sulk depending on the situation and/or your mood

Let me know if you have any futher questions, and I promise that you'll enjoy [**Evernote**](http://www.evernote.com) if forced to use it. It's the business!

Answer (score 0):

The select all, print, PDF worked beautifully. I can't tell you how long I tried to find an easy way. You did! SO cool!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! 
This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.